# Allocate free space on a partition inside an extended

Tags: partitioning

- /dev/sda2 - EXT4 - 136GB of free space

  - /dev/sda3 Extended
  - /dev/sda5 - ext4 - my ubuntu partition
  - /dev/sda6  linux swamp

I need to put those 136GB from /dev/sda2 into /dev/sda5, but apparently, because they are separate by the extended partition I cannot allocate the freespace.

Do you guys know how can I do it without formating?

Answer (score 1):

Shrink sda2 and then expand the extended partition (sda3), and then expand sda5.